# How should I scale this multidimenstional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have an input array (best represented by a tree) with a varying depth, such as `[1, 2, [3, [4, 5], 6], 7]`. What I want is to perform an action on each one of the elements (that isn't an array) and put them into a new array with the same depth structure.

My original plan was to have a function that handles the non-array elements, but when it reaches an array to call itself with that array as input. The issue with this approach is that the variables are not separate between the two times the function is called, so if it recurs the variables from the first will get mixed with the second.

Any solutions? I'm looking for either a way to recur a function without them sharing variables, or a better algorithm for crawling through the array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your explanation of the variables not being separate, but you can handle this with simple recursion. If it's an array, recurse, otherwise scale the number:

```js
let a = [1, 2, [3, [4, 5], 6], 7]

function scale(a, n){
  return a.map(i => Array.isArray(i) ? scale(i, n) : i * n) 
}

console.log(scale(a, 10))
```